# Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении 2

Tags: пунктуация

Не прошло и месяца, и тут такой удар!

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Здесь тире просится.

Comment: А если без тире? Это оба безличных предложения?.. Тогда не надо запятой...

Comment: А, вон откуда у вас это поползновение...  Ладно, сейчас отпишусь...

Comment: См. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133). При отсутствии синонимичных слов запятая ставится: Нету чудес, и мечтать о них нечего. Между тем совсем рассвело, и надо было опять выходить в море.

Comment: Значит, нужна запятая?!

Comment: Да, именно так. Ответил подробно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А если без тире? Это оба безличных предложения?.. Тогда не надо запятой.

Я бы не сказал, что второе - однозначно безличное, тут вопрос, что считать главным членом - и современная модель грамматики, насколько понимаю, не дает прямого и бесспорного ответа.

Но даже если так, правило-то не так просто звучит, что если-де два безличных, то и запятой не надо.

> По правилам есть несколько ситуаций, когда постановка запятой между
>   частями ССП перед "и" не нужна.
>
> Запятая не ставится, если: ... 
>   - объединены два безличных предложения,
>   имеющие в своем составе синонимичные члены: *"Необходимо закутать горло
>   шарфом и надо попытаться прополоскать его содой", - советовали врачи
>   внезапно потерявшему голос Деду Морозу*.

http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37435.php

Даю по источнику, автору которого я доверяю по части методологии изложения. Хотя и тут надо бы оговорить, что не в составе предложений, а в составе главных членов (по старой школьной программе - сказуемых). Это некое подобие однородности придаточных, главной части, как понимаете, тут нет, но есть некое единство грамматической и синтаксической функции у частей, соединенных союзом "и". В этом аналогия. Поэтому и запятая не требуется.

Но у нас, в вашем примере, даже отдаленно нет ничего похожего на синонимичность или хотя бы какую-то общую семантико-грамматическую роль главных членов, они вообще из разных сфер. "Прошло" и "тут" (если считать второе безличным).

Так что без запятой (или тире, которое я продолжаю рекомендовать) - никак.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вечные сомнения...